# New printer only visible in some applications

Tags: macos, printing

I installed a couple of new printers via `System preferences -> Printers & Scanners -> + -> IP`.

They work just fine from some applications. For example from adobe reader or inkscape I can print without problems.

**Problem:**

They don't show up in the printer list for native mac applications like preview.app.

How can I add them to the list of printers available in preview.app?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like an HP. Did you select "HP JetDirect" from the first pop-up menu? I think that LPD Printer is selected by default and HP printers don't work and play well that way...

Comment: @SteveChambers Its both lexmark and hp printers.

Comment: Yes: what protocol did you use? Do these printers not announce themselves through Bonjour (mDNS) (i.e. show up on the first pane of Add Printer..) ??

Comment: @benwiggy I added them via their IP address. I don't know their Bonjour names

Comment: @user3180943 My point is: Did they not show up in the first panel of the Add Printer panel?

Comment: @benwiggy I don't know. The first panel shows dozens of printers in the whole building. I only know the IP addresses of the ones I want to add, not their bonjour names, so I don't know if they are part of this list and if yes which ones they are